# How do I integration test an SharePoint Online App?

Tags: client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, testing, unit-testing

It is my understanding that if I want to do integration testing of Apps for SPO I first and foremost need a tenant to do the testing on. The problem is, how do I run the tests? Ideally I want to use a test runner so that I get reports. But how can a test runner make CSOM-requests to SharePoint Online when it runs outside the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your app on your local farm for testing purpose then when you feel comfortable you can deploy on your SP Online and do the others tests